# VB shared to C# static

Tags: .net, vb.net, c#-4.0, migration

I'm doing code conversion in my project and ran into a statement that give me this error "The type initializer threw an exception static class".

In Vba it works perfectly

```
Shared Sub New()
    _instance = New Setting
End Sub
```

I use some tools to convert it into c# into this statement which gives me that error

```
public const string id = "Resources";
private static PeModelSetting _instance;
static Setting()
{
    _instance = new Setting();
}

// and access the function like this
Setting.GetConfig(Setting.id)
```

Does anyone has any idea how to resolve this issues? I tried to make changes in the c# code by changing it into non static Contructor, which will stop giving me the error, but the problem is all of the method inside this Setting class are static type which will give me another error "cannot access instance reference".

I can change all the method to non static, but the problem is there are hundred of files that are accessing this class, and modifying all of it is a pain in the ass. Is there any other way to do this? the best is the Setting class can remain static.

Comment: What happens in the instance level default constructor of the Setting-class? Which field initializers (both for static as for instance Level fields) does the class contain?

Comment: there is only one static constructor and _instance is a variable 
private static Setting _instance;

Comment: Are there any initializers for id or any other fields?

Comment: Note that the first code is VB.NET, not VBA. You have to post more code (at least, the definition of the Class of this constructor and the declaration of `_instance` and `id`) in order to understand what are you "misconverting".